# Plotting the following surface in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot the surface given by `f(x,y) = 1/(1-xy)` over the range `[0,1]×[0,1]`, with the plot range being `[0,5]`.

[image]

Update: I managed to obtain the above plot, but I want the red region to be smoothly connected. How can this be achieved without dramatically increasing the sampling frequency of the plot?

Perhaps there is a way to weight the sampling according to some arbitrary function?

My code:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1,xmax=1,ymax=1,zmax=10,samples=50,
  unbounded coords=jump, filter point/.code={%
        \pgfmathparse
          {\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x} + \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y} > 1.8}%
            \ifpgfmathfloatcomparison
              \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/x}{nan}%
            \fi
          },
        ]
  \addplot3[surf] {1/(1-x*y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Use the `smooth` option.

Comment: @manooooh I get a horrible thing. https://imgur.com/a/rJPzxBq

Comment: Post your code here.  Don't post an image elsewhere.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have added my code to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguably simplest way to go is to clip the corners away.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1,xmax=1,ymax=1,zmax=10,samples=50]
  \clip (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)  -- (1,0.8,0) -- (1,0.8,5) -- plot[variable=\t,domain=1:0.8]
  (\t,{4/(5*\t)},5) -- (0.8,1,5) --  (0,1,5) -- (0,0,5) -- cycle;
  \addplot3[surf] {min(1/(1-x*y),5.2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: any importance of 1.6 instead of 1.8?

Comment: @JackLam It is 1.16, and the answer is yes. In older versions you need to prepend the coordinates used in the clip path with `axis cs:`.

Comment: Overleaf does not allow the use of 1.16. Do you have a workaround?

Comment: @JackLam Try `compat=newest`. Most likely this will work, if not, use `\clip (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0,0)  -- (axis cs:1,0.8,0) -- (axis cs:1,0.8,5) -- plot[variable=\t,domain=1:0.8]
  (axis cs:\t,{4/(5*\t)},5) -- (axis cs:0.8,1,5) --  (axis cs:0,1,5) -- (axis cs:0,0,5) -- cycle;`.